# I am training an autoencoder for anomaly detection. How can I incorporate anomalous data in training using a custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.10709.pdf) paper suggests the following algorithm that incorporates anomalous data points into the training process:

Algorithm 1 Autoencoding Binary Classifiers

```
while not converged do:
  Sample minibatch {(x1, y1), · · · , (xK , yK )} from dataset 
  Compute the gradient of θ as g0 (using custom loss function that incorporates the label of x) 
  Perform SGD-update for θ with gθ 
end while
```

I have the following code for an autoencoder implemented using keras:

```
class AnomalyDetector(Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(AnomalyDetector, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")])
    
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(140, activation="sigmoid")])
    
  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = AnomalyDetector()
```

My main problem is: how do I include the labels in a customly defined loss function if an autoencoder's input and output must be X. Assuming I encode the label as a feature, during inference, the label won't be available, so I am not sure how to implement the algorithm described by the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Add the labels to y and split them up again in your loss function:

```py
# dummy input
x = tf.random.uniform((100, 140))  # dummy data
y = tf.reshape(tf.cast((x[:, 0] < 0.5), x.dtype), (-1, 1))  # dummy labels
y = tf.concat((x, y), axis=-1)  # dummy data + labels

def loss_fn(true, pred):
    def L_FN(true, pred):
        return tf.abs(tf.subtract(true, pred))

    true_label = true[:, -1:]  # separation
    true_x = true[:, :-1]
    fn = L_FN(true_x, pred)
    loss1 = tf.multiply(true_label, fn)
    loss2 = tf.multiply(tf.subtract(1.0, true_label), tf.math.log(tf.subtract(1.0, tf.math.exp(-fn))))
    loss = tf.subtract(loss1, loss2)
    return loss

autoencoder = AnomalyDetector()  # needs your AE code
autoencoder.compile('sgd', loss_fn)
```

In the loss function, the true prediction and the label gets separated again. Because the label is only in `y` (or `true`), the model prediction is not affected. The loss function should be the one from the paper (AE for the L_FN(x), not DAE).

Comment: Why true_label = true[:, -1:]  instead of true_label = true[-1:] ?

Comment: The shape of `true_label` is `(batch_size, labels)`. We want all from the batches, but only the last label, the added one. `:` is short for "take everything from this axis". In other words, it means "from all batches, take the last label". `-1:` also preserves the axis, because it is a slice from the last element to the end (which is just one one this axis). `-1` (without the `:` after) would take the same element, but the axis would be gone. I hope I could make it clear. You can also take a look into array slicing.